# Rendering "fat" mesh based lines for geometry edges in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, line, mesh

With the following code:

```
       import * as THREE from 'three';
       import { Line2 } from 'three/addons/lines/Line2';
       import { LineGeometry } from 'three/addons/lines/LineGeometry';
       import { LineMaterial } from 'three/addons/lines/LineMaterial';
       import { LineSegmentsGeometry } from 'three/addons/lines/LineSegmentsGeometry';
       // ...
        const edge_mode = "gl_lines"; // or "fat_lines"
        const thresholdAngle = 15;
        const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(geometry, thresholdAngle);
        switch(edge_mode){
            case("gl_lines"):{
                const lines = new THREE.LineSegments(edges, this.line_material(line_material) );
                group.add( lines );
                this.rest_on_ground_plane(lines);
            }break;
            case("fat_lines"):{
                let line_geometry = new THREE.LineSegmentsGeometry().fromEdgesGeometry( edges );
                
                
                //const line_geometry = new LineGeometry();
                //line_geometry.setGeometry( geometry );
                const line_material = new LineMaterial( {
                    color: primary_line_color,
                    linewidth: 5, // in world units with size attenuation, pixels otherwise
                    vertexColors: true,
                    //resolution:  // to be set by renderer, eventually
                    dashed: false,
                    alphaToCoverage: true,
                } );
                //let lines = new THREE.LineSegments(geometry, material);
                const lines = new Line2( line_geometry, line_material );
                lines.computeLineDistances();
                lines.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
                group.add( lines );
                this.rest_on_ground_plane(lines);
            }break;
        }
```

when I set edge_mode to "gl_lines" it works as expected. It renders the outlines of my mesh (please see the screenshot below).

[image: gl lines mesh edges rendered in THREE.js]

I am now trying to implement the "fat_lines" version which replaces the old gl_lines implementation with triangle mesh based lines instead. It has been hard to do because the documentation is all over the place and nobody seems to have done it.

In this code I get a basic error `TypeError: THREE.LineSegmentsGeometry is not a constructor`, which hints that I didn't even manage to import correctly.

So how would I go about this?

Comment: Examples: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat_wireframe.html or https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_wireframe.html.

Comment: @WestLangley: I already looked at those and they show how to draw fat lines directly and how to draw a model as wireframe, however they don't show hot to use fat lines for edge geometry. But I found a solution that worked and if nobody else replies I will upload it myself.

Comment: "But I found a solution that worked and if nobody else replies I will upload it myself." Do post your answer anyway. Others might be able to comment to help its efficiency or implementation.